# Checking if two int arrays have duplicate elements, and extract one of the duplicate elements from them

Tags: java, arrays, unique

I'm trying to write a method, union(), that will return an int array, and it takes two int array parameters and check if they are sets, or in other words have duplicates between them. I wrote another method, isSet(), it takes one array argument and check if the array is a set. The problem is I want to check if the two arrays in the union method have duplicates between them, if they do, I want to extract one of the duplicates and put it in the unionArray[] int array. This is what I tried so far.

```
public int[] union(int[] array1, int[] array2){
  
  int count = 0;
  if (isSet(array1) && isSet(array2)){
     for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
           if (array1[i] == array2[j]){ 
              System.out.println(array2[j]);
              count ++;
           }
        }
     }
  }
  int[] array3 = new int[array2.length - count];
     
  int[] unionArray = new int[array1.length + array3.length];
  int elementOfUnion = 0;
      
  for (int i = 0; i< array1.length; i++){
     unionArray[i] = array1[i];
     elementOfUnion = i + 1 ;
  }
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = elementOfUnion; i < unionArray.length; i++){
     unionArray[i] = array3[index];
     index++;
  }
  
  
  return unionArray;
}


public boolean isSet(int[] array){
  boolean duplicates = true;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     for(int n = i+1; n < array.length; n++){
        if (array[i] == array[n])
           duplicates = false;
     }
  }
     
  return duplicates;
}
```

What I was trying to do is to use all of array1 elements in the unionArray, check if array2 has any duplicates with array1, and then move all the non-duplicate elements from array2 to a new array3, and concatenate array3 to unionArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be much easier to do it with `Collection` API or `Stream` API. However, you have mentioned that you want to do it purely using arrays and without importing any class, it will require a few lengthy (although simple) processing units. The most important theories that drive the logic is how (given below) a union is calculated:

```
n(A U B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A ∩ B)
```

and

```
n(Only A) = n(A) - n(A ∩ B)
n(Only B) = n(B) - n(A ∩ B)
```

A high-level summary of this solution is depicted with the following diagram:

[image]

Rest of the logic has been very clearly mentioned through comments in the code itself.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 }));
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 }));
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }));
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 3, 4 }));
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 4, 5 }));
        display(union(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, new int[] { 7, 8 }));
    }

    public static int[] union(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        // Create an array of the length equal to that of the smaller of the two array
        // parameters
        int[] intersection = new int[array1.length <= array2.length ? array1.length : array2.length];
        int count = 0;

        // Put the duplicate elements into intersection[]
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                    intersection[count++] = array1[i];
                }
            }
        }

        // Create int []union of the length as per the n(A U B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A ∩ B)
        int[] union = new int[array1.length + array2.length - count];

        // Copy array1[] minus intersection[] into union[]
        int lastIndex = copySourceOnly(array1, intersection, union, count, 0);

        // Copy array2[] minus intersection[] into union[]
        lastIndex = copySourceOnly(array2, intersection, union, count, lastIndex);

        // Copy intersection[] into union[]
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            union[lastIndex + i] = intersection[i];
        }

        return union;
    }

    static int copySourceOnly(int[] source, int[] exclude, int[] target, int count, int startWith) {
        int j, lastIndex = startWith;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            // Check if source[i] is present in intersection[]
            for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                if (source[i] == exclude[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If j has reached count, it means `break;` was not executed i.e. source[i] is
            // not present in intersection[]
            if (j == count) {
                target[lastIndex++] = source[i];

            }
        }
        return lastIndex;
    }

    static void display(int arr[]) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i < arr.length - 1 ? arr[i] + ", " : arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java's streams could make this quite simpler:

```
public int[] union(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    return Stream.of(array1, array2).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).distinct().toArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned this is a class assignment, so I cant use any other methods, I can only use the most basic stuff, or I have to write my own methods.

Answer (score 2):

Even with all the restrictions of only using arrays, you can simplify your code a lot. No need to check for `sets`. Just :

1. allocate an array to store all elements of the union (*i.e.,* `int[] tmp_union` ), which at worst will be all elements from both arrays `array1` and `array2`.
2. iterate over the elements of `array1` and compared them against the elements from `tmp_union` array, add them into the `tmp_union` array only if **they were not yet added** to that array.
3. Repeat 2) for the `array2`.

During this process keep track of the number of elements added to the `tmp_union` array so far (*i.e.,* `added_so_far`). In the end, copy the elements from the `tmp_union` array into a new array (*i.e.,* `unionArray`) with space allocated just for the union elements. The code would look something like:

```
public static int[] union(int[] array1, int[] array2){
    int[] tmp_union = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int added_so_far = add_unique(array1, tmp_union, 0);
        added_so_far = add_unique(array2, tmp_union, added_so_far);
    return copyArray(tmp_union, added_so_far);
}

private static int[] copyArray(int[] ori, int size) {
    int[] dest = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        dest[i] = ori[i];
    return dest;
}

private static int add_unique(int[] array, int[] union, int added_so_far) {
    for (int element : array)
        if (!is_present(union, added_so_far, element))
            union[added_so_far++] = element;
    return added_so_far;
}

private static boolean is_present(int[] union, int added_so_far, int element) {
    for (int z = 0; z < added_so_far; z++)
         if (element == union[z])
             return true;
    return false;
}
```